# Polylines setLatLngs

Tags: polyline-creation

I am trying to give a polyline a new set of co ordinates from a server. When trying to use the .setLatLngs method to redraw the new line with updated co ordinates i get the error "Uncaught TypeError: a.setLatLngs is not a function". Am I using this method incorrectly? If so how do i use this method?

```
var a = new L.LatLng(0,0),
    b = new L.LatLng(0,0);


var polyline = new L.Polyline([a, b]).addTo(mymap);

//this is inside an ajax query
    a.setLatLngs([latA1,lonA1]);
    b.setLatLngs([latA6,lonA6]);


//latA1, lonA1 are new points for a point on the line
//latA6, lonA6 are new points for a point on the line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured why the setLatLngs method wasnt working for me. I was passing in coordinates to the method rather than passing in the polyline itself.

```
//working code

 polyline.setLatLngs([ [latA1, lonA1] ,[latA5,lonA5] ]);
```